# Are functions being changed during assignment?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I thought I had a good handle on how Python passes objects ([this article seemed enlightening](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)).

Then I tried something simple, just assigning functions to variables.

```
class Thingy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = {"egg": [1], "spam": [2]}
    def calc(self):
        self.foo["egg"][0] = 3
        self.foo["spam"][0] = 4
    def egg(self):
        return self.foo["egg"][0]
    def spam(self):
        return self.foo["spam"]

thingy = Thingy()
x = thingy.egg()
y = thingy.spam()

print(x) # prints 1
print(y[0]) # prints 2
print(thingy.foo)
thingy.calc()
print(x) # prints 1 (???)
print(y[0]) # prints 4
print(thingy.foo)
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on, especially as the value in the dictionary has been updated. My guess is that when the variable `x` is assigned, it is actually referring to a function whose return value has been evaluated to "1" already.

Is my understanding correct? I'd appreciate a clear explanation of why Python is deciding to treat `.egg()` and `.spam()` differently.

Comment: It doesn't treat them differently; `egg` returns an immutable value (an integer), `spam` returns a mutable one (a list).

Comment: "Then I tried something simple, just assigning functions to variables." - you're not assigning functions to variables. You're calling methods and assigning the returned objects to variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements

```
x = thingy.egg()
y = thingy.spam()
```

create `x` as an integer and `y` as a list. But what you must know is that the line `y = thingy.spam()` is just a shallow copy.
This is how shallow copy  is defined by [medium](https://medium.com/@manjuladube/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c) :

> Shallow copy is a bit-wise copy of an object. A new object is created that has an exact copy of the values in the original object. If any of the fields of the object are references to other objects, just the reference addresses are copied i.e., only the memory address is copied.

So the variable `y` contains the address (or reference in more layman's term) to the elements of the list, and changing the list changes it also, unlike `x` where a new memory location is assigned.

Answer (score -1):

when you run

```
x = thingy.egg()
```

`thingy.egg()` return an int witch has the same value as the one in foo["egg"][0] ans is than assigned to x whereas

```
y = thingy.spam()
```

thingy.spam() returns a list containing 4 witch is the same list as `foo["spam"]`. This has to do with object mutability. In your calculate function the 2 integers `foo["egg"][0]` and `foo["spam"][0]` are redefined with new objects. However the lists hey are contained in remaine as the same object. As x refers to the integer it remains the old object so 1 and y alsow stays as the same object however that object is a list and its first element now refers to the new int object witch is 4

Comment: "if you return an intager and assign it to a variable it will create a new object" - false. This [does not create a new object](https://ideone.com/ry9Kab).